# Checking Verified Email in Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

```
$url = trim("https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus"); //Sandbox URL
$API_UserName = "XXXXXXX";
$API_Password = "XXXXXXX";
$API_Signature ="XXXXXXX";
$API_AppID = "APP-80W284485P519543T";
$API_RequestFormat = "NV";
$API_ResponseFormat = "NV";

$bodyparams = array ("requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US",
                     "emailAddress" =>"xxxx@gmail.com",
                     "firstName" =>"XXX",
                     "lastName" =>"YYY",
                     "matchCriteria" => "NAME"
                    );
$body_data = http_build_query($bodyparams, "", chr(38));
```

I am doing above code but it gives me no any output. Anyone can suggest me where I am wrong?

If I am using following URL

```
$url = trim("https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus"); //Paypal URL
```

Then It gives me following Response

```
responseEnvelope.timestamp: 2016-09-28T23%3A24%3A41.132-07%3A00
responseEnvelope.ack: Failure
responseEnvelope.correlationId: 192ed30d1b3d7
responseEnvelope.build: 24397612
error(0).errorId: 560022
error(0).domain: PLATFORM
error(0).subdomain: Application
error(0).severity: Error
error(0).category: Application
error(0).message: The+X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID+header+contains+an+invalid+value
error(0).parameter(0): X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID
```

Comment: what about this `The X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID header contains an invalid value`

Comment: Check your `X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID`

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu I am using **Sandbox URL** Account. I do not have **APP-ID** for Paypal Account

Comment: but error code 560022 is comes when your ID is not valid. Cross check your sandbox accout

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu I cant get you. Which ID is not valid. Can you give me modified code Which I given.

Comment: Check this link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/permissions/RequestPermissions_API_Operation/

Comment: As per their doc "560022 Invalid API Caller Account"

Comment: Yes I am getting **560022** error. Then What I should do for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124499/discussion-between-sadikhasan-and-dipanwita-kundu).

Comment: @devpro Can you help me in my code?

Answer (score 0):

We strongly recommend you downloading [adaptiveaccounts](https://github.com/paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php) demo for your testing.
Which includes the getVerfiedStatus API call in the demo.